# New Tabs into product details and strings - Luma theme

Tags: luma-theme, magento-2.1.7

How can I add new tabs in Luma theme to show more information about created attributes?

In the small description in the Italian view I leave the string "none", with code inspection the class is "type".

I tried to change the text of the product in the Italian view but it does not work.

Please help me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you want to show in the tab?

Comment: Do you want to show custom attribute value in tab ?

Comment: The attributes created in Stores / Attributes / Product should be on the board and inserted into the attribute set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to add a static block to hold the additional information about created attributes you can use below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
      <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="additionalinfo.tab" as="additionalinfo" group="detailed_info" >
            <arguments>
             <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Addtional Information</argument>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">additionalinfo</argument>
            </arguments>
      </block>
   </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

This would go in your theme within file:

```
Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
```

A block will need to be created called `additionalinfo` and the information within here will be displayed in your tab. Similarly you can use phtml files that are shown instead of the static block.

Comment: What is the full path where I need to enter this code?

Comment: Have you got a theme?

Comment: app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

Comment: after app/design/frontend/ i have only Magento folder and not Vendor.

Comment: Yeah so you do not have a theme. May be worth creating a theme. Within Magento is there any folders?

Comment: Io uso Luma nella gerarchia app è: design/frontend/Magento/luma or blank in luma folder there is only the folder i18n

Comment: You can just add that file within the luma folder (add the Magento_Catalog/layout folders in there) if that is what your theme is set as this should add your tab.

Comment: And after create into layout a file catalog_product_view.xml with code top?

Comment: Yeah that's the one

Comment: You may need to run deploy static content depending on which mode your magento is in.

Comment: I tried to create the folder and everything else by doing the deploy but it does not work

Comment: I update catalog_product_view.xml into /public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout with a block and now work but is correct? Why with create Magento_Catalog etc not found?

Answer (score 0):

Override `catalog_product_view.xml` in your module and add your block in  `product.info.details` reference block as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>      
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
           <block class="Path/to/Block" name="nameofblock" template="Vendor_Module::path/to/template" group="detailed_info" >
             <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Title of the tab</argument>
             </arguments>
          </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Feel free ask any queries.